# How to install nitrux os?

Tags: ubuntu, usb, bootable

I would like to install [Nitrux OS](https://nxos.org/) on my computer, which I like because of its beautiful design. I currently have Ubuntu installed, downloaded the Nitrux ISO and would now like to create a bootable USB. So far all attempts that I tried did not seem to work (Rufus, start up disk creator, dd,...)'

Is there something special with this OS? According to the website it has to be "deployed not installed" even though I think this would be after initially booting it from a usb. Do I maybe have to change some config in Ubuntu so that  the bootable device will be recognised?

Comment: Hi and welcome to [unix.se]! As you probably know from the other Stack Exchange sites, questions are more likely to be well-received and helpfully answered when they show that you've tried to find the required information yourself. Seems you've had a glance at Nitrux's official documentation, but missed the most important part, so some members are marking your question as "doesn't show enough effort". That happens, so don't fret about it too much, check out [ask] and the [tour] if you haven't already, and your future questions will work out just fine. :)

Comment: And to everyone downvoting: the reason may be obvious for long-term members, but for a question from a new contributor please leave a comment explaining what should be improved.

Comment: `Is there something special with this OS?` - yes. You are supposed to wipe out all your existing partitions.

Comment: Like I've said on your other comment, there's little stopping you installing it on a USB stick.

Answer (score 8):

The first section in the "[Compendium](https://nxos.org/en/compendium/)" (documentation) is the topic "How can I take this great Linux distribution for a spin?." It clearly states that the ISO is not a Hybrid boot, and that Rufus and other generic boot utilities will not work:

> **Deploying Nitrux to a PC**
>   **How to deploy Nitrux to your storage device.**
>
> Our ISO is a standard ISO-9660 bootable image. However, our ISO
>   dramatically differs from other conventional Linux ISO files in that
>   ours is not a hybrid-ISO image and this means that the ONLY way to use
>   Nitrux is deploying the ISO image using znx.
>
> We DO NOT recommend that you flash the ISO raw to a storage device AT
>   ALL, please use znx.
>
> We DO NOT recommend using Rufus, YUMI neither we recommend Unetbootin
>   nor Multiboot or any tool to write the ISO image raw to the device.
>
> You can deploy the ISO from an existing Linux environment by
>   downloading the znx AppImage.

It then gives the link for this *znx AppImage*, along with step-by-step instructions for performing the installation.

Comment: trying to follow the "compendium": `sudo ./znx init /dev/sda5` on a newly created partition works fine, but `sudo ./znx deploy /dev/sda5 nitrux/1-1-4 nitrux_release_stable-v-1-1-4.iso` gives `znx: Error: Device has not been initialized.` - What's wrong? - A separate problem is that the last command works on a 8GB usb stick, but then my laptop wouldn't boot from that, not even after following [this](https://www.facebook.com/Nitrux/posts/hey-guysif-youre-having-problems-booting-up-the-live-session-after-using-unetboo/1353204498096884/).

Comment: I think that "Compendium" is far from being sufficiently detailed (while being uselessly pretentious).

Comment: You didn't follow [the instructions](https://nxos.org/en/compendium/#deploying-nitrux-konsole) correctly. `sudo ./znx init /dev/sda` (which will wipe the ENTIRE `sda` disk), and then `sudo ./znx deploy /dev/sda ...`. The instructions state quite clearly that "_the initialization and the deployment are done to the storage device and not a partition, znx will automatically handle partitioning._"

Comment: I understand now. I had read the instruction but couldn't believe a new Linux would ask me to delete all my partitions before installing. Sadly, that means i will never use a such Linux.

Comment: I don't see why you couldn't deploy to a USB stick, but it does seem a shame there's no live edition doesn't it.

Comment: Yes, but that's nothing compared to what I mentioned: absolute requirement to delete all partitions in order to install this Linux. Preposterous. Windows 10 is not that brutal. I guess the nitrux guys and girls should start selling laptops with their pretious thing preinstalled.

Comment: So deploy it to a USB stick then. You'll erase the entire USB stick but your main machine will remain untouched.